# Does there exist a formula of first-order logic that is satisfiable only on structures with infinite domains?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am curious to know if there exists a formula of first-order logic *without identity =*, that is satisfiable only on structures with infinite domain.

Does there exist such a formula, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Why do you think there is such formula?

Comment: Would provide more info ? what is the first "order logic" ? or infinite structure , ..

Comment: @Cardinal: First-order logic is a standard term, as is "infinite structure".

Comment: Ok, :) I Must take a look at google :)

Comment: Voted to reopen. Intuitively, Mauro's answer should work -- with a bit of tweaking. If you make the domain of discussion explicit with a predicate $D$, e.g. $\forall x:[D(x) \implies \neg R(x,x)]$, etc., it may be possible to prove that $\{x:D(x)\}$ is Dedekind-infinite.

Answer (score 8):

If the semantics does not allow for the empty structure, you can see :

- Stephen Cole Kleene, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=uV6Sp8gl3PcC&pg=PA293) (1967 - Dover ed  2002), page 293 :

> > $\forall x \lnot R(x,x) \land \forall x \forall y \forall z (R(x,y) \land R(y,z) \to R(x,z)) \land \forall x \exists y R(x,y)$.

Comment: I guess most first order logics assume that the universe isn't empty.

Comment: @DanielV: it is customary to set up the model theory of first order logic so that the universe is not empty, but some authors do not require that. However, you can add $\exists x\exists yR(x, y)$ to Mauro's axiom to exclude the case of an empty universe.

Comment: I wonder if this is the shortest FOL statement with only an infinitely sized interpretation.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA what does this statement mean?

Comment: @scifie Try making a directed graph with 3 points that satisfies the above relation (R(x, y) means there is an arrow from point x to point y).

Comment: This is basically 2 of the axioms of peano arithmetic, "The successor of a natural is a natural" as $\forall x \exists y ~S(x)=y$ becomes $\forall x \exists y R(x, y)$ and "Successor is injective" as $\forall x,y Sx=Sy \implies x=y$" is modified to become $\forall xyz R(x,y) \land R(y, z) \implies R(x,z) \land \forall x \lnot R(x,x)$.  The other axioms of peano arithmetic aren't necessary to establish that the natural numbers are not finite.

Comment: @scifie - read the formula with $<$ in place of $R$ ...

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA doesn't this statement mean that there doesn't exist a "Greatest" element?

Comment: @scifie - Yes; because the part $\forall x \lnot R(x,x)$ precludes the possibility of a "cycle"...

Comment: Can this be proven to be equivalent to any of the standard definitions of infinity, e.g. Dedekind-infinite?

Comment: Can a structure that satisfies these conditions be shown to be Dedekind-infinite?

Comment: Consider the domain to be $\{a,b,c\}$ and $R$ to be the edge relation for directed graphs. Then a graph with three nodes $\{a,b,c\}$ with all possible edges apart from self-loops satisfy this model, right?

Comment: @helperFunction - are you thinking at a sort of "triangle": $R(a,b)$ and $R(b,c)$ and $R(a,c)$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes

Comment: If so, we need $R(c, \text {something})$ and not $R(a,c)$.

Comment: So basically $R$ is irreflexive + transitive + left-total and $\exists x \top$.

Answer (score 4):

Given any sentence with equality which is satisfied only in infinite structures, you can get one without equality by replacing $=$ with an equivalence relation everywhere.  That is, replace every instance of $=$ by a new binary relation symbol $R$ and add a subsentence saying $R$ is an equivalence relation to your sentence.