# Is ths FOL structure necessarily infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Follow up to question: [Formula that's only satisfiable in infinite structures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381409/formula-thats-only-satisfiable-in-infinite-structures)

Suppose we have predicates $D$ and $R$ such that :

1. $\exists x: D(x)$
2. $\forall x:[D(x) \implies \neg R(x,x)]$
3. $\forall x, y, z: [D(x) \land D(y) \land D(z) \implies [R(x,y) \land
           R(y,z) \implies R(x,z)]]$
4. $\forall x:[D(x) \implies \exists y: [D(y) \land R(x,y)]]$

**Q:** If we also have set $S$ such that $\forall x:[x\in S\iff D(x)]$, is  $S$ necessarily infinite? Can we, for example, construct an injective function $f: S\to S$ that is not surjective, thus establishing that $S$ is Dedekind-infinite? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the graph with vertices $\{x : D(x) \}$ and edges $\{(x,y) : D(x) \wedge D(y) \wedge R(x, y) \}$.  The conditions state that this graph is (1) non-empty, (2) simple (no self-edges), (3) transitive, and (4) sink-free (every vertex has at least one outgoing edge).  Because it's transitive and simple, it can't have any loops... so it's a DAG.  And because it's sink-free and non-empty, it must have infinite depth.  Indeed, we can generate an infinite chain by induction: starting with any vertex (guaranteed by (1)), follow the link to a new vertex (guaranteed by (4)), and note that the new vertex can't be the same as any already-visited vertex (by (2) and (3)).

Comment: Thanks. I tried something like that using AC. I was able to prove that the resulting mapping was not surjective (at the starting point), but was unable to prove it injective.