# Finite Domain of First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Validity in first order logic is semidecidable, that's I would need infinite interpretation in order to prove the validity of a formula. 
Why this happens even if I use a finite domain for the interpretation? Is it possible to show it with an example?

Comment: We can prove the validity of a f-o formula with an argument. Consider e.g. $x=x$; we do not have to review **all** (infinite many) interpretations to conclude that it has no counterexamples.

Comment: Consider the formula in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381409/formula-thats-only-satisfiable-in-infinite-structures) for an example of a formula that is satisfiable only in an infinite structure.

Comment: @hardmath It sounds like you're saying that if $\varphi$ fails to be valid (true in all models), then it has a finite countermodel. That's not right - take $\varphi$ to be the negation of any consistent sentence which has only infinite models. But maybe I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: @AlexKruckman : Yes, you are correct.  I'll try to rephrase.

Answer (score 7):

A consequence of [Trakhtenbrot's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trakhtenbrot%27s_theorem) is that finite validity (or equivalently, finite unsatisfiability) in first-order logic is not semi-decidable (and in particular undecidable). By finite validity (resp. unsatisfability) I mean the fact that a first-order formula is true in every (resp. no) interpretation with finite domain.

It also implies that finite satisfiability (the fact that a first-order formula is true in some interpretation with finite domain) is semi-decidable but not decidable.

A nice (but technical) presentation of Trakhtenbrot's theorem and its cocnseqences is available [here](https://www.dbai.tuwien.ac.at/staff/pichler/dbt/slides/dbt04.pdf).

Comment: +1. To the OP, note the switch from the infinite to the finite case: when we consider infinite models, validity is semidecidable and satisfiability is not semidecidable, whereas in the context of finite models it's the other way around. (Also note that validity of $\varphi$ on *only infinite* models is equivalent to the validity of $\Gamma_\varphi=\varphi\cup\{\psi_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $\psi_i$ is the sentence saying that the domain has $>i$-many elements; since $\Gamma_\varphi$ can be gotten computably from $\varphi$ the usual completeness theorem gives us the desired semidecidability.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Yes, good remark. It could also helps from a mnemonic point of view.

Comment: Another good source for this material is Libkin's *Elements of Finite Model Theory*.  It presents essentially the same proof of Trakhtenbrot's theorem as the linked slides.