# finding set of formulas of first-order logic that satisfies a infinite domains

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I was wondering what is the set of formulas of first-order logic that is satisfiable only iff the size of the domain is 3?

I was also wondering how we can use the above formulas to find another set of formulas that is satisfactory iff the size of the domain is infinite.

I'm pretty confused about how I can cook up some formulas and link one question to another, any help will be appreciated

I have found another answer here [Does there exist a formula of first-order logic that is satisfiable only on structures with infinite domains?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381409/does-there-exist-a-formula-of-first-order-logic-that-is-satisfiable-only-on-stru)
but I'm not sure how to find a SET of formulas for infinite and size 3 domain

Comment: for the 3-elements domain it is quite easy: $\exists x_1 \exists x_2 \exists x_3 \ldots$ adding the clause that the three must be different and the "closure clause that $\forall z(z=x_1 \lor z=x_2 \lor z=x_3)$

Comment: But in what sense are you searching for a formula that is satisfied only by 3-elements **and** infinite domains? If it has 3 elements the domain is not infinite and it it is infinite it has more than 3 elements.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA right, my teacher said as a hint that we can find the infinite domains with help from the 3-elements question, but I am not sure how

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what would the set of formulas using infinite domain be ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA shouldn't it be X = ∀(=1 & =2 & =3) where & is conjuction because only then will X valuate to true, as it contains exactly 3 elements?

Answer (score 1):

As Mauro mentioned in his comment, a formula that is satisfiable iff the size of the domain is *at least* 3 is, $$\exists x_1,\exists x_2, \exists x_3(x_1\neq x_2 \wedge x_1\neq x_3 \wedge x_2\neq x_3).$$

If you want those to be the *only* 3 elements then you also need the universal statement Mauro mentioned.

Similar to the existential formula, you can write a formula that is satisfiable iff the size of the domain is *at least 4*.

You can do this for every $n$ and have a set of formulas that is satisfiable iff the domain is infinite (note that you don't want the universal formula previously mentioned to be a part of this set).